# How to install python-dev using rpm for python 2.6.8?

Tags: python, numpy, rpm

I am trying to install BioPython in a newly established linux server. To install BioPython, NumPy is required. I downloaded the numpy-1.6.2 and tried to install it but it gives an error message

```
File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 271, in check_types
"Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

So, I need to install python-dev first but I find no way of doing it in my system. The python version I have is 2.6.8 and the only package manager installed is rpm. I have root access but I am not very familiar to administrative issues. Can anybody give me an idea how I can do this?

Comment: You might be better off installing anaconda. It will get you to 2.7 with numpy and scipy pre-packaged. https://anaconda.org

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install it with

```
rpm -i package.rpm
```

with

```
rpm -qa
```

you should be able to search the correct name of the package (if I remember, on rpm bsaed distro it should be something like python-devel.x.y.z.rpm)

Comment: I didnt find any package python-dev........ with rpm -qa command. May be I should upgrade my python version because I can see that python-dev is available for python-2.6.7 and for python-2.7. but not for python 2.6.8. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I use a PC fedora 21 and encountered the same issue.
I directly typed dnf install python-devel in the Terminal.
May be you can try.

```
[YB@localhost ~]$ rpm -qa |grep python-dev
```

python-devel-2.7.8-15.fc21.i686